# A direct sum of semisimple left R-modules is semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum, semi-simple-rings

We define a ring has unity and semisimple module is a direct sum of simple submodules.

There is a theorem states that

> A direct sum of semisimple left $R$-modules is semisimple.

Proof: Suppose $M=\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i$, 
where $M_i$ is semisimple module.
Since $M_i$ is semisimple, 
we write $M_i=\bigoplus_{j\in J_i}M_{ij}$, 
where $M_{ij}$ is simple module.
Therefore, we have 
$$M=\bigoplus_{i\in I}\left(\bigoplus_{j\in J_i}M_{ij}\right).$$

**My Question**:
How do I proof that $M$ is still a **direct sum**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are hesitating because you are worried about checking condition for internal direct sums?

Think of it this way: you can view $M_i$ as an external direct sum of simple modules.  Then you are forming an external direct sum of the $M_i$.

Then writing $$M=\bigoplus_{i\in I}\left(\bigoplus_{j\in J_i}M_{ij}\right)$$

is really no different than forming $J=\{(i,j)\mid i\in I, j\in J_i\}$

$$M=\bigoplus_{(i,j)\in J}M_{ij}$$

and every $M_{ij}$ is a simple $R$ module, so...

You could also argue with isomorphisms that the two things are the same, too, if you want to chase some arrows.

Comment: Thanks. That was just my question. 
But I used the Theorem 2.4 in Lam's _A First Course in Noncommutative Rings_ to avoid checking the condition.
That is, it is sufficient to show that $M=\sum_{i\in I}\left(\sum_{j\in J_i}M_{ij}\right)$.